# Alias don't work even with alias command handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a command handler in my `main.js` file and alias handler is in it too - But when I try to run a command with the alias I've set in `module.exports.config` it does not respond.

This is my command handler:

```js
fs.readdir(`./commands/`, (error, files) => {
  if (error) {return console.log("Error while trying to get the commmands.");};
  files.forEach(file => {
      const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
      const commandName = file.split(".")[0];

      client.commands.set(commandName, command);

      if (command.aliases) {
          command.aliases.forEach(alias => {
            client.aliases.set(alias, command.name)
          });
      };
  });
});


client.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type === "dm") return;

  let prefix = (";");
  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let cmd = messageArray[0].toLowerCase();
  let args = messageArray.slice(1)

  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  let commandfile = client.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)) || client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)))
  if(commandfile) commandfile.run(client,message,args)

})
```

And this is my `module.exports.config`:

```js
module.exports.config = {
  name: "eval",
  description: "Eval a code",
  aliases: ['debug']
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a new collection for the aliases. You could use collection's [`.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) method and check if there is an alias with the command name.

So, inside `fs.readdir` you only set `client.commands` and when there is an incoming message, you can check if there is an exact command name (using `client.commands.get`) and if there is not, you check if the command has an `aliases` property. If it has, you can check if the `aliases` array [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the command.

Also, if you use `cmd.slice(prefix.length)` in more than one place and you don't use `cmd` anywhere, then you probably need to remove the prefix from the command.

The following should work as expected:

```js
fs.readdir(`./commands/`, (error, files) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return console.log('Error while trying to get the commmands.');
  }
  files.forEach((file) => {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    const commandName = file.split('.')[0];

    client.commands.set(commandName, command);
  });
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  let prefix = ';';
  if (
    message.author.bot ||
    message.channel.type === 'dm' ||
    !message.content.startsWith(prefix)
  )
    return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const command =
    client.commands.get(commandName) ||
    client.commands.find((cmd) => cmd.config?.aliases?.includes(commandName));

  if (!command) return;

  try {
    command.run(client, message, args);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('There was an error trying to run that command:');
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: That looks good, but even with this code when I type ;debug instead of ;eval it doesnt send anything..

Comment: Oh, of course, you exported an object with a `config` object so you need to use `cmd.config.aliases`. I've just updated my code.

Comment: Just noticed  that if the command doesnt exist it sends: (node:11304) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'aliases' of undefined

Comment: if you spam like ;sdijgrwj, it sends this error

Comment: Basically I need to define if there's alias or not

Comment: You can use optional chaining like `cmd.config?.aliases?.includes(commandName)` but it requires at least Node v14. I've just updated my code again.

Comment: client.commands.set(commandName, command);
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Comment: I use v14.15.1.

Comment: Have you deleted the `client.commands` collection somewhere? I haven't changed anything related to it.

Comment: omg I didn't notice that I deleted it, sorry. Works perfectly for now! <3